# Can you set the attribute !important to multiple css values at once?

Tags: html, css

Could you do something like this? I've looked around and couldn't find anything.

```
!important {
footer {
    color: white;
}
.socialNetwork li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.bar {
    background: white;
    height: 10px;
    width: 550px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
}
```

Comment: No. !important should be used scarely and with caution, so there won't be a feature to support macro-ing it.

Comment: Gut says no, it's a per-property thing. Related note, what in god's name are you doing that requires that much `!important`? (If it's not a userstyle I've got bad news for you...)

Comment: Well Im using bootstrap for the footer of a php file and the template im using for a form messes up bc of the bootstrap and its wayyyyy to convaluted to mess with

Comment: Just add the rules AFTER the main CSS file. that would have the same effect.

Comment: I'm using a CDN for bootstrap and the footer is stilll goin to require it even if the top needs it to be gone. Oh actually I thought of something while I was doing this. Is there way way to put a bootstrap cdn while inside of a .php template that gets linked to another page. This .php template though is not the header .php template and I need two seperate templates bc they are required for a project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, because [!important is not a selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors).  Also see the [advice on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception):

> Using !important is bad practice and should be avoided because it
>   makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in
>   your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the
>   !important rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with
>   greater specificity will be applied.
>   ...
>
> - Always look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important
> - Never use !important on site-wide CSS

Instead, you'll want to review the order of the CSS you are setting, and then see how they [cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade), overriding as needed.

Comment: I know its bad I just wanted to know if you could do it but anyway thank you for the answer heres you check mark :D

Comment: Just to add to MDN's sage advice on when to use it.... It's also "okay" to use in __hotfixes__ which you'll be patching properly when your hair is no longer on fire, for __shorthand classes__ (ex: `.rel { position:relative !important; }`) that make no sense to use without their effect and are only used to save on locs from `style` attribs, and when you're __hacking a third-party style__ (userstyles, third party widgets, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why you trying to do this, but this syntax or similar doesn't exist.

Using `!important` in everything isn't good either, see details about it in [this post](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/).